# TensorFlow (2.x) models for genetic algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, tensorflow2.0

I am building a small tool to train neural networks in Unity environments using genetic algorithms

For the moment I am using my own little class to instantiate dense neural networks, which is really simple and fast

I was planning to use TensorFlow 2.x instead, to benefit from a solid and modular framework, possibly using more complex neural net architectures etc.

The thing is, TensorFlow models are waaay slower to instantiate, by a factor of >16000. I haven't compared inference yet but instantiation alone kills the benefit of using TensorFlow

I know that TensorFlow is made for graph differentiation and not for genetic algorithms, but I would really benefit from its modularity and simplicity

**Do you see any solution that might fit my need ?**

Thanks

Comment: I myself am using tf 2.0 with GA for weight optimization, and times when I found it better than my own implementation was with recurrent and cnn structures -- i am using eager mode and gpu. With just shallow dense layer tf seemed like overkill, especially beacuse we do not need derivatives.

Comment: Could you tell me how can you benefit from gpu in your GA ?

Comment: i ve used gpu for inference, especially for large populations, then mutate/crossed in cpu and again infer on gpu and so on... EDIT: If you are indifferent for type of EA, tf provide diff. evolution in tfp module already implemented.

Comment: I see, it might not fit my need since I depend on a Unity environement implying that I have a limited number of agents running at the same time and that inference needs to be inbetween each time step. But thanks for your help